# Prolog Successor Arithmetic

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

I have a knowledge base with the following:

```
numeral(0).
numeral(s(X)) :- numeral(X).
numeral(X+Y) :- numeral(X), numeral(Y).

add(0,X,X).
add(s(X),Y,s(Z)) :- add(X,Y,Z).

add2(W+X,Y+Z,R) :- add(W,X,A),add(Y,Z,T),add2(A,T,R).
add2(X+Y,Z,R) :- add(X,Y,A),add2(A,Z,R).
add2(X,Y+Z,R) :- add(Y,Z,A),add2(X,A,R).
add2(X,Y,R) :-  add(X,Y,R).
```

which evaluates correctly queries such as:

```
?- add2(s(0)+s(s(0)), s(s(0)), Z).
Z = s(s(s(s(s(0)))))

?- add2(0, s(0)+s(s(0)), Z).
Z = s(s(s(0)))

?- add2(s(s(0)), s(0)+s(s(0)), Z).
Z = s(s(s(s(s(0)))))
```

However the following query is evaluated to:

```
?- add2(s(0)+s(0), s(0+s(s(0))), Z).
Z = s(s(s(0+s(s(0))))) .
```

But the required output is:

```
?- add2(s(0)+s(0), s(0+s(s(0))), Z).
Z = s(s(s(s(s(0)))))
```

I know the issue is with the line:

```
add2(W+X,Y+Z,R) :- add(W,X,A),add(Y,Z,T),add2(A,T,R).
```

But i just can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to call `add2/3` recursively with the first two calls as well. So use `add2(W+X,Y+Z,R) :- add2(W,X,A),add2(Y,Z,T),add2(A,T,R).`. But if you want a pure Prolog implementation, you will need to alter the code more drastically.

Comment: I'm getting no change in output with that implementation.

Comment: The form is a little peculiar. Why the extra complication of having in-line addition in two different arguments that are then added together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you make the problem more complex by handling the cases with an `add2/3` predicate. You first need to resolve the structure of the first two arguments to something of the shape `s(s(...s(0)...))`.

In order to do this, we can make an `resolve/2` function that looks for `(+)/2` terms and recursively works with `add/3`:

```
resolve(0,0).
resolve(s(X),s(Y)) :-
    resolve(X,Y).
resolve(X+Y,Z) :-
    resolve(X,RX),
    resolve(Y,RY),
    add(RX,RY,Z).
```

So now for a grammar:

```
E -> 0
E -> s(E)
E -> E + E
```

`resolve/2` will convert this to a grammar with:

```
E -> 0
E -> s(E)
```

For example:

```
?- resolve(s(0)+s(0),X).
X = s(s(0)).

?- resolve(s(0+s(s(0))),X).
X = s(s(s(0))).
```

And now our `add2/3` predicate will first `resolve/2` the operands, and then add these together:

```
add2(A,B,C) :-
    resolve(A,RA),
    resolve(B,RB),
    add(RA,RB,C).
```

The sample queries you then write resolve to:

```
?- add2(s(0)+s(s(0)), s(s(0)), Z).
Z = s(s(s(s(s(0))))).

?- add2(0, s(0)+s(s(0)), Z).
Z = s(s(s(0))).

?- add2(s(s(0)), s(0)+s(s(0)), Z).
Z = s(s(s(s(s(0))))).

?- add2(s(0)+s(0), s(0+s(s(0))), Z).
Z = s(s(s(s(s(0))))).
```

Comment: thank you very much for simplifying the method. i knew my approach was unnecessarily complex. Appreciate the explanation!

Comment: suppose i was to introduce the symbol p as a negative number so that queries would evaluate like     ?- add2(p(0)+s(s(0)),s(s(0)),Z).
Z = s(s(s(0))) is it possible to extend you previous solution or does that require drastic changes to the code?

Comment: i figured it out. Thanks @Willem

Comment: @oreillsf: sorry, was not online :s.